# Does a 1 year break in career hinders the chance of new job IT job

Tags: security, cisco

I have 3 years experience as web developer as small Linux /window server networking.
I had to go to overseas (home country) for some reason for about 1 year.

I was thinking of doing some certification so that i can expand my knowledge.

I am thinkking of finishing CCNP , CCSP and RHCE and some MS SQL certification.

I just want to know that after coming back will that 1 year gap can hinder my way i getting new job.

Os any way so that i can utilize that 1 year that can help in my career. I want to get out of we development

Comment: should be a wiki

Answer (score 2):

Returning from a 1 year break is anything but insurmountable.  Admittedly, it doesn't sound like you have a huge amount of experience in system administration (vs web development), which is likely to significantly reduce your chances of getting a role as an system administrator.

My advice?  I would start at the bottom level of a company which is overtly passionate about the technologies you wish to work with.  Yes, this probably means a help desk role or similar and get some experience from the ground up. Need to crawl before you can walk.

Comment: I agree with Keiran's post.  From my point of view, a break in IT is not a problem, so long as you have the skills the employer is looking for and a confident in your presentation (and I don't mean over selling yourself).

Personally I don't put much value on CCNA/MCSE type certifications (but thats not to say that they don't have a place).  Instead I look at experience and tend to present scenario type questions during an interview to see how the prospective employee would react and respond.  To me that is more important than having completed an exam.

Comment: Agreed. CCNA/MSCE without experience don't really tell me if you can cut it on the job.  Experience means a lot more.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that a one-year break in any field will require some explaining that might be difficult.

Certifications will help, but no matter what you'll have to give a good reason for the gap in your resume when asked.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend taking every bit of initiative and gaining certifications, Nothing looks better than long term work experience and passing certifications.  Employers are not always looking for the best, they are looking for people who take pride in what they do and want to do it day in day out for years.